# Google Cloud Platform Connect to PostgreSQL Server from Cloud Functions Using Internal DNS Name

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I try to connect Functions to PostgreSQL server with internal DNS name.

As note, I have create and set serverless VPC connector correctly.

The internal DNS name I use is based on this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#instancenames

This is the connection setting look like

```
const client = new Client({
        user: process.env.USER,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        host: 'sql-instance.c.my-project.internal',
        port: process.env.PORT,
        database: process.env.DATABASE
    })
```

But it always show error like this

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sql-instance.c.my-project.internal sql-instance.c.my-project.internal:5432 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)

If I tried to use internal server address like this

```
const client = new Client({
        user: process.env.USER,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        host: '10.0.3.6',
        port: process.env.PORT,
        database: process.env.DATABASE
    })
```

this works fine. But I'm afraid that the internal ip changed so I want to use internal DNS name.

Is there a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an intended behavior, as is mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#connecting_to), for private connections, the only way to reach an Cloud SQL instance from a function is by using explicitly the IP.

The IPs (public/private) on a Cloud SQL are static, that means these IPs are reserved for each instance and not going to be changed or re-utilized until removing the IP from the instance or by deleting the instance.

If you turn off your instance, you can see that the IPs (public/private) still assigned.

The zonal DNS is only available for [Compute Engine VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#instancenames).